# Console output of string shows as concatenated segments

Tags: node.js

I have a file containing some text representing a valid Json object and read into a `string` variable `S`. When I tried to display parts of this string, I get different output rendering in Node REPL. For example, `S.substring(0, 70)` produces:

```
'[\r\n  {\r\n    "n": 0,\r\n    "t": "“quotes”",\r\n    "s": [\r\n      [],\r\n    '
```

But `S.substring(0, 80)` produces this:

```
'[\r\n' +
  '  {\r\n' +
  '    "n": 0,\r\n' +
  '    "t": "“quotes”",\r\n' +
  '    "s": [\r\n' +
  '      [],\r\n' +
  '      []\r\n' +
  '    '
```

`S.substring(0, 80).toString()` produces the same output.

Is there some rule specifying how strings are displayed? Is it possible to have strings show up as one continuous string of characters even if it is long?

Comment: This is the first time I see that string is split this way... I can't reproduce it in terminal. Just to be sure - can't it be IDE or environment post processing?

Comment: The original file is beautified in VS Code editor as can be seen by lots of spaces for indent and new lines. But as the first example shows, it can be displayed as one continuous string. I also think I am seeing such formatting for the first time today. I am using Node v14.19.0. Invoking the `toString()` method on the second example still produces the split output.